# Compiled perl executable fails to run on Windows 7 (64 bit)

Tags: perl, executable, 32bit-64bit, exe, runtime-error

I have created an executable (.exe) of a perl script on a 64-bit linux kernel. It executes correctly in this environment.

When the executable is run in 64-bit Windows 7, the following error message is displayed:

> The version of this file is not compatible with the version of Windows
>   you're running. Check your computer's system information to see
>   whether you need x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the program,
>   and then contact the software publisher.

Given that the source and destination OS's were both 64-bit, I'm not sure that the architecture of the build is the issue. Are there any special considerations to make a compiled perl program execute properly in Windows? Thank you.

Comment: Did you compile with a windows target? Taking a linux ELF binary and renaming it to "myapp.exe" isn't going to work.

Comment: Hi @MarcB. Thanks for the suggestion. No, I did not -- could you tell me how to compile for a windows target?

Comment: @MarcB: By, the way, I compiled by issuing the command `pp -x -o out.exe in.pl` within bash.

Comment: That'd compile a linux executable and call it "out.exe". It won't be a Windows PE binary, it'll be a Linux ELF binary, and neither is portable between fundamentally different operating systems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Executable files are not compatible across platforms. They will run on the original platform only unless they are explicitly cross-compiled to a different target. That's actually the reason we use interpreted languages. What you want to do is not possible because the Windows and Linux APIs, libraries, and well just about everything are completely different.

This is why you need to download a different version of a program for linux/windows/mac.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Dan. I suppose that is obvious now that I think about it (though I never tried cross-platform compiling before).

Comment: +1 Dan FTW!  @User001 If you used the Active State compiler, the license includes compilers for Windows as well as Linux.  In that case just recompile on the Windows box with the Windows version.

Comment: Thanks, @T.Rob. If I used the ActiveState compiler, I was not aware that I did so. I compiled on a bash terminal in debian by issuing the following command: `pp -x -o out.exe in.pl`. Is there a simple way to instruct the compiler (in linux) to create the executable for a Windows platform?

Comment: Ha! Good question. I'm hoping @MarcB will answer because I took the lazy way out and used a compiler that runs native on Windows.  I was lucky enough to have been able to expense the cost of the Perl Dev kit so I've never had to deal with cross-compilation.

Comment: PAR/pp don't do cross-"compilation" at all. You'll have to build your executable on a Windows machine. PAR/pp work just fine there. I suggest Strawberry Perl, but ActivePerl is as good nowadays.

Comment: Thanks @tsee: I downloaded ActiveState perl and the PAR package, but am not able to compile a windows binary.